# get value from input and pass it to controller and firebase query

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys I'm trying to query my database with the input from html. But data from input is not passed to query. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Html:

```
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" placeholder="Student name" ng-model="input.studentName">
</label>
```

controller:

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseObject, $ionicUser, $state, $ionicAuth) {

$scope.userData = $ionicUser.details;

$scope.input = { studentName:''}


var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users/'+ $scope.input.studentName);
$scope.users = $firebaseObject(ref);
```

If I input name it doesnt query but if I I set input manually to

```
 $scope.input = { studentName:'Michael'}
```

it works fine.

Comment: Where are you registering your controller and attaching it to the view?

Comment: its done in ionic creator

Comment: When you call query in firebase after click on button?

Comment: No it is calling the query once when running the app but i thought it will update when the input will change?